# Need help on session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, webmethod

How do i return a Userid in web method and use that returned result in website ASP.NET,make it session variable in order to use it on different webpages in ASP.NET?

[WebMethod]
        public bool UserLogin(string EmailAdd, string Password)
        {

```
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"user id=BankUser;password=Computer1;server=(local)\sql2008;database=BillionBank;");
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [BillionBank].[dbo].[tblCustomerProfile] WHERE EmailAdd='" + EmailAdd + "' AND Password ='" + Password + "'", myConnection);
        SqlDataReader myreader;
        myreader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (myreader.Read())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

this is my code i want to return a Userid as a result and use it in website as a session variables,when am calling the web method in my website

Comment: from where to return Userid ? can u elaborate ? or else if you have UserID u can use Session["UserID"] = yourvalue and access it every where/

Comment: please enter a code snippet ,so that we can understand in a better way

Comment: You can the value of session on the page itself than why r u going to create web method.

Comment: Any one with some solutions please help.:-(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public string GetUserID(string EmailAdd, string Password)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"user id=BankUser;password=Computer1;server=(local)\sql2008;database=BillionBank;");
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [BillionBank].[dbo].[tblCustomerProfile] WHERE EmailAdd='" + EmailAdd + "' AND Password ='" + Password + "'", myConnection);
        SqlDataReader myreader;
        string result = "";

        myreader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (myreader.Read())
        {
            result = Convert.ToString(myreader["UserID"]);
        }

        return result;

    }

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserID"] = GetUserID(YOUR_EMAILID, YOUR_PASSWORD);
}
```

Comment: am getting an error:"Use of unassigned local variable 'Userid'" and "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" this are the errors am getting.

Comment: Covert the Object you are getting from Reader. and also do check if UserID exists in the Select * Query of Sql server

Comment: Now am getting more errors,remember am passing values to the sql database to actually log the user in and return the userid,am getting error:No overload for method GetUserID takes 0 arguments

Comment: Still not working, Am getting the following errors: Error 1 "Invalid token '[' in class, struct, or interface member declaration",Error 2 "Invalid token '"UserID"' in class, struct, or interface member declaration",Error 3 "Identifier expected",Error 4 Method must have a return type.

Comment: double click on Error and it will take u to the line on which error exists.

Comment: getting error at line 38 which is Session["UserID"] = GetUserID();

Comment: Ofcource you have to pass two parameter in that. Session["UserID"] = GetUserID (your_Email_ID, Your_Password);

Comment: that is the full web method for login page,becouse some of the web method have no errors are completly running,this is the one i have a porblem with. Anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: see it out. i guess you have not put that session line in any function. because of which u getting error.

Comment: Thanks any way the web method is up and running.

Answer (score 1):

In the web method set the session variable like:

```
Session["userId"] = 1234;
```

Then within your application you can just call the session again. Note you'll need to parse the session to int again

```
int userId
if(int.TryParse(Session["userId"].toString(), out userId)
{
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On A webmethod keep a `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` then you can return session variable.